# Deleting a NodeJs app from server

Tags: node.js

I have configured a server for NodeJS and ran a **Hello World** app at the **localhost:8080**.

I am configuring a server for first time, so i have just tested my server with this app. Now i want to run another app at the **localhost:8080**. So i have tried to delete previous app, which is running from a **hello.js** file -

```
sudo rm -rf hello.js
```

File is deleted now but the app is still running at **localhost:8080**. I have tested with `curl http://localhost:8080/` and found the result of the deleted app -

```
Hello World!
```

How can i delete this app perfectly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `killall node` or `pkill node`.
2. Or alternatively, you can do:

   - `ps aux | grep node`
   - `kill -9 <pid>`
     (You get **pid**s from the `ps` command.)

Beware that these will stop all `Node.js` servers. Exercise caution.

Comment: This returns **-bash: killall: command not found** . My OS is **Debian GNU 8.6**

Comment: @ni8mr I added a bunch of alternatives.

Comment: @ni8mr  If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. Thanks!